# How To Print Out A <List>Reference object in java?

Tags: facebook, spring, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I am using spring social api to create a facebook application. I am using `List<Reference> friends = facebook.friendOperations().getFriends();` to get a list of my friends. I want to print out the list but when i do it just prints out

`[org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Reference@7606931d,`

I have tried using the

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}
```

But it still just prints out the references. Is there anyway to print out what i need?

Comment: A list holds multiple items, like an array. You will need to loop through the list and print each item in the list individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the list of references, and print each of them individually, like this:

```
for (Reference friend : friends) {
    System.out.println(friend.getName());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was it. I was doing this before but i was trying to print out "friends" and that didnt have a .getName() but now i realize i had to print out friend.getName();